# How to post on instagram using api with branded tags i.e. with paid partnership tag?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

Having trouble in getting the exact endpoint to post on instagram using branded tags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the Content Publishing API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

`POST /{ig-user-id}/media` — upload media and create media containers.

`POST /{ig-user-id}/media_publish` — publish uploaded media using their media containers.

Comment: Not only content publish but want to add tag like paid partnership with. As you may have seen on many celeb posts promoting some brand. Is it possible using api?

Answer (score -1):

"Branded content tags are not supported."
Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing